# Changing only one letter when there are a lot simular in string

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have the following string:

```
I.like.football
sky.is.blue
```

I need to make a loop that changes the last '.' to '_' so it looks this way

```
I.like_football
sky.is_blue
```

They are all simular style(3 words, 3 dots).
How to do that in a loop?

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fU2xG8/2)

Comment: "Added the problem". Where?? Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str='I.like.football'

str=str.rsplit('.',1) #this split from right but only first '.'
print '_'.join(str) # then join it
#output I.like_football

in single line
str='_'.join(str.rsplit('.',1))
```

Comment: You really ought to use a different variable name than [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` lets you specify the number of replacements. Unfortunately there is no `str.rreplace`, so you'd need to reverse the string before and after :) eg.

```
>>> def f(s):
...     return s[::-1].replace(".", "_", 1)[::-1]
... 
>>> f('I.like.football')
'I.like_football'
>>> f('sky.is.blue')
'sky.is_blue'
```

Alternatively you could use one of `str.rpartition`, `str.rsplit`, `str.rfind`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't even need to run in a loop:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\.(?=[^\.]+$)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"I.like.football\nsky.is.blue"
subst = u"_"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```